# Calling one command in Yargs calls other commands as well

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yargs

I am learning nodejs and yargs and tried to implement it in my code using command function.

I am trying to make a `CLI` based note taking app.

I have two files `app.js` and `utils.js`, I run `app.js` and `utils.js` is imported in `app.js` to use functions in it.

There is a problem that I cannot debug, when calling `app.js` with `remove` option it is automatically also calling `add` command even when it is not being called explicitly by remove command.

**Input:**

```js
node app.js remove --title="hello"
```

**Output:**

```js
{ _: [ 'remove' ], title: 'hello', '$0': 'app.js' }
Already exists!
Operation successful!
```

**This is my `app.js`:**

```js
// import modules
const validator = require('validator');
const yargs = require('yargs');
// const chalk = require('chalk');
const utils = require('./utils.js');

// version

yargs.version('1.0.0');

const argv = yargs.argv;
console.log(argv);
const command = argv._[0];

// commands
yargs.command({
    command: 'add',
    describe: 'Add a new note',
    builder: {
        overwrite: {
            describe: 'Overwrite the existing file',
            demandOption: true,
            type: 'boolean'
        },
        title: {
            describe: 'Title of the note',
            demandOption: true,
            type: 'string'
        },
        body: {
            body: 'Body of the note',
            demandOption: true,
            type: 'string'
        }
    },
    handler: utils.addNote(argv.overwrite, argv.title, argv.body)
});

yargs.command({
    command: 'remove',
    describe: 'Remove a note by its title',
    builder: {
        title: {
            describe: 'Title to search for',
            demandOption: true,
            type: 'string'
        }
    },
    handler: utils.removeNote(argv.title)
});

// eof
yargs.parse()
```

**This is my `utils.js`:**

```js
// import
const fs = require('fs');

// load notes
function loadNote() {
    try {
        const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync('notes.json');
        const stringData = dataBuffer.toString();
        const dataJson = JSON.parse(stringData);
        return dataJson;
    } catch (e) {
        return [];
    }
}

// add note
function addNote(overwrite, title, body) {
    const newNote = {
        "title": title,
        "body": body
    };

    const dataJson = loadNote();
    if (overwrite) {
        fs.writeFileSync('notes.json', JSON.stringify([newNote]));
        console.log("Operation successful!");
    } else {
        let flag = true;
        dataJson.forEach(function (object) {
            if (object.title === title) {
                flag = false;
            }
        });
        if (flag) {
            dataJson.push(newNote);
            fs.writeFileSync('notes.json', JSON.stringify(dataJson));
            console.log("Operation successful!");
        } else {
            console.log("Already exists!");
        }
    }
}

// remove notes
function removeNote(title) {
    const dataJson = loadNote();
    dataJson.filter((object) => object.title !== title);
    fs.writeFileSync('notes.json', JSON.stringify(dataJson));
    console.log("Operation successful!");
}

// export
module.exports = {
    addNote: addNote,
    removeNote: removeNote,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem in my code and it appears that the `handler:` property of `yargs.command` needs an *Anonymous Function* as its value. I believe that this is because your `command` basically serves as the "name" of your function. Otherwise, it is treated as a regular function call.
So, you need to have either `handler: function(){/*yourFunction()*/}` or
`handler: ()=>{/*yourFunction()*/}`. I'll show a more detailed example with my code...

**My `app.js`**

```
const yargs = require('yargs')
const notes = require('./notes')


//set the app.js version
yargs.version('0.5.0')

//set the notes directory
const dir = './MyNotes'

/**
 *  Commands
 */
// Add a note
yargs.command({
    command: 'add',
    describe: 'Adds a new note',
    builder: {
        'title':{
            describe: 'Note Title',
            demandOption: true,
            type: 'string'
        },
        'body':{
            describe: 'The contents of the note',
            demandOption: true,
            type: 'string'
        }
    },
    handler: (argv)=>{notes.addNote(argv.title,argv.body,dir)}
})


// Remove a note
yargs.command({
    command: 'remove',
    describe: 'Removes the specified note.',
    builder:{
        title:{
            describe: 'Title of the note you want to remove.',
            type: 'string',
            demandOption: true
        }
    },
    handler:(argv)=>{notes.removeNote(argv.title,dir)}
})

// Read a note
yargs.command({
    command: 'read',
    describe: 'Reads the specified note.',
    builder: {
        title:{
            describe: 'The title of the note you want to read.',
            type: 'string',
            demandOption: true
        }
    },
    handler: (argv)=>{notes.readNote(argv.title,dir)}
})

// List the notes in the directory
yargs.command({
    command: 'list',
    describe: 'Lists all notes in the directory.',
    handler: ()=>{notes.listNotes(dir)}
})
//parse the arguments to execute the commands
yargs.parse()
```

Let's look at the last command "`list`"; if you remove the arrow function around `notes.listNotes(dir)`...

```
yargs.command({
    command: 'list',
    describe: 'Lists all notes in the directory.',
    handler: notes.listNotes(dir)
})
```

I will get a list of all the notes in my `./MyNotes` directory **every time** I run a command (even if it is a different command).

As you are refactoring your code, please keep in mind that `argv` is created and parsed during **runtime**. After `argv` is created, it is parsed and passed to `handler:`. This means that you have to pass `argv` to your anonymous function **before** you access any of its members within the function. As seen with my "read" command:

```
// Read a note
yargs.command({
    command: 'read',
    describe: 'Reads the specified note.',
    builder: {
        title:{
            describe: 'The title of the note you want to read.',
            type: 'string',
            demandOption: true
        }
    },
    handler: (argv)=>{notes.readNote(argv.title,dir)}
})
```

If I did not pass `argv` to the function,
`()=>{notes.readNote(argv.title,dir)}`
I would get the error message `ReferenceError: argv is not defined`. I did not need to pass a variable to the anonymous function of my `list` command because `dir` is defined during **compile time**
`const dir = './MyNotes'`.

I hope this helps! :D